# Extend admin/login.phtml: Invalid template file

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, template, login

I try to override admin login template, using Layout Block Argument. Here is the files I created to do that:

in Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/admin_login.xml
I tried:

```
<referenceBlock name="admin.login">
   <arguments>
     <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">vendor_module::admin/login.phtml</argument>
   </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

But nothing Happened, so I changed with:

```
<referenceBlock name="admin.login">
   <action method="setTemplate">
     <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">vendor_module::admin/login.phtml</argument>
   </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

And now in magento2/var/log/system.log I have:

**main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file**: 'vendor_module::admin/login.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'admin.login'

I have created the template file login.phtml in **Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/admin/**

so I don't know what's I'm doing wrong. I'm very new to Magento 2, I took the time to read Dev Docs and many forums but I can't find the solution by myself, anyone could help me?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Did you use **V**endor_**M**odule or **v**endor_**m**odule?

Module path in layout config is defined as **V**endor_**M**odule, not **v**endor_**m**odule. Notice the uppercase in bold text.

For example, your module path is `Project\Distributor`, you call the module as `Project_Distributor` in layout config.

To change admin login block template, method 1:

```
<referenceBlock name="admin.login" template="Vendor_Module::admin/login.phtml" />
```

Or method 2:

```
<referenceBlock name="admin.login">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::admin/login.phtml</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

The filename is `adminhtml_auth_login.xml`, not `admin_login.xml`.
Source: [Magento 2 DevDoc](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#set_template)

Make sure that your block template file path is `/path/to/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/admin/login.phtml`. Notice that view, adminhtml, and templates are in lowercase.

After modifying your xml, flush magento cache (cache:flush), then reload your web browser.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer - yes I did, I made a mistake when writing vendor_module. The problem is elsewhere...

Comment: I have updated my answer, about the filename. Could you try it?

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't know what's I'm doing wrong, but method 1 gives: `main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'Rcdevs_Openotp::admin/login.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'admin.login'`, and method 2 do nothing. I have the correct file path in lowercase... Are you sure this method works for this particular case?

Comment: I FOUND MY MISTAKE!!! If you have a vendor and a module name like mine, VENdor and ModULE (in this case it's strange but it's my case...) you HAVE TO write VENdor_ModULE not Vendor_Module like explained in all doc and forums! Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, as I have warned you about the case sensitive...

Answer (score 0):

In fact the problem come from that I'm not able to find a block to extend corresponding to login.phtml (**view/adminhtml/templates/admin/login.phtml**), if I enable printing block and template in Magento admin, I can see that the block name I should extend is **\Magento\Backend\Block\Template**, so I try to extend this one but it's a "top level" class. What I try:
I created a block:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Backend\Admin;

class Login extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{
}
```

Add this line to my di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Backend\Admin\Login"/>
```

And create my Layout Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-login" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>

     <referenceBlock name="admin.login">
          <block class="Rcdevs\Openotp\Block\Adminhtml\Backend\Admin\Login" name="admin_login" template="admin/login.phtml" />
      </referenceBlock>      

</body>
```

and my view/adminhtml/templates/admin/login.phtml with the content I'd like to change.

The admin.login block has been well replaced with my template, but now the problem is because it's not a "particular block" all the phtml using \Magento\Backend\Block\Template are necessarily impacted and showing this message in system.log:

**main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'admin/login_buttons.phtml' in module: 'Vendor_Module' block's name: 'adminhtml_auth_login_buttons'**

What can I do extend admin/login.phtml (admin.login block) only without touching others blocks?
Thank you very much..